# How can I customize instances of a template xib

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib, nib

I'm learning about xib files and just starting to understand why people use them as well as or instead of storyboards. My question is about how and when it's appropriate to use the xib as a "template".

Let's say I have a xib mapped to my custom UIView subclass - I know how to set that up in IB - and my xib has a UILabel subview.  This is a very simplified example just for the purposes of the question, but basically I'm trying to create a view that can be reused for each screen of an iOS "introduction" walkthru, like the panels of https://github.com/MatthewYork/MYBlurIntroductionView

So I want to set most of what's in the view up at design time, and most of it will be common to each instance. The text I want to put in the UILabel is going to be static (i.e. I know it now at design-time) but each instance of the view will have different text. So let's say that I want to position the UILabel in different places in each instance, depending on how much text is in it etc and whether it's covering something else important.  Now, I know I could do this programmatically, i.e. have the label as a @property linked up in IB and then set frame position in the code, but as far as I understand it the beauty of using xibs is that you can do known things like this at design-time.

As far as I can see my options are:

1. Load new instances of the xib and set the position etc programmatically as mentioned above (would rather not if possible)
2. Create my template xib, setting all the common stuff, and then make copies of it "CustomView1.xib", "CustomView2.xib", etc.  (a bit yuck but not too bad)
3. After creating my template xib, use the storyboard to drag in new UIViews and somehow set each to be linked to my one "CustomView.xib", and then somehow do my static repositioning of the subview UILabel within each of those UIView instances on the storyboard.  Is that possible?  If so that'd be great.  Obviously I know I can set each of those UIViews to be instances of my UIView subclass, but I'm just missing the link between doing that and customising each instance.  Does the file's owner have something to do with it?

Comment: If you're going to go with option 3, then there's really no need for the xib at all. You can create the view in the storyboard, copy and paste it as many times as you want, and modify them as necessary (of course these will be view controllers, not just views).

Comment: @rdelmar Yeah but I'd lose any ability to change something in one place, e.g. say I want to change the background color of all of these views.  I thought that maybe somehow the xib could help me there, i.e. I'd change it just once in the xib, and then instances would all get that change.  And I'm really talking about views (maybe VCs as well but for my purposes the xib would be representing a UIView).